# Get right timezone information when using datetime.datetime.now()?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to get the date in datetime.datetime.now() format but for MT time in Python 2.7.

If you suggest using a library please explain how to install it. Thanks.

Comment: See information about `pytz` in the [`datetime.tzinfo` Objects](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#tzinfo-objects) documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from pytz import timezone
from datetime import datetime
datetime.now(timezone('US/Mountain'))
```

That's what you probably need. As for installing the library, just `pip install pytz`

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help