# Date conversion on server in different timezone

Tags: python, scrapy, pytz

I have a date string (event occurrence) in local time (scraped from a web page using Scrapy) and I need to convert it to a timestamp. I do this using:

```
return int(time.mktime(time.strptime(dateString, "%Y-%m-%d")))
```

That gives me a time stamp that I store in my database. Every day I scrape the page for new data so I need to compare dates. I use the same function as above to convert to a timestamp that I compare with the timestamp in the database. This way I avoid duplicate records.

When I run this script locally (scheduled task) everything works as expected. However, when I run it on a remote server the conversion results in a different timestamp which means I end up with duplicate records. This is because I have pre-populated my database locally.

In my app which needs to display the actual date that the event occurred i have the following:

```
 /**
 * @summary Format date string
 *
 * @param date {Integer} Unix time stamp
 *
 * @return date {String}
 */
function formatDate( date ) {
    var m_names = new Array( "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec" ),
        d = new Date( date ),
        curr_date = d.getUTCDate(),
        curr_month = d.getUTCMonth(),
        curr_year = d.getUTCFullYear();

    return curr_date + "-" + m_names[ curr_month ] + "-" + curr_year;
}
```

Since my app can display records (events) in several timezones at the same time, I need to ensure that the event date is correctly displayed.

I need some advice on how I can best achieve the desired result.

Comment: Convert all timestamps to UTC as soon as possible. See question [_Get right timezone information when using datetime.datetime.now()?_](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39939286/get-right-timezone-information-when-using-datetime-datetime-now)

Comment: That makes sense in that I will be comparing apples to apples. However, how do I do that? As well, I need to display the actual date in an app and since the app can show data in 9 time zones, how do I show the right date?

Comment: Just convert to local time when needed (which may mean you'll need to store the original timezone some where/how).

Comment: @martineau Converting dates to UTC is best for *timestamps*, but it is not good advice for storing future events which are scheduled in local time, since the mapping between UTC and local time is not fixed for events in the future.

Comment: @Paul: While it's true that the mapping between UTC and local time varies over the course of time, I believe the it  _is_ fixed for any given date and time — so converting UTC back to local using the mapping in effect on that date and time will be correct.

Comment: @martineau No, it is fixed for any given point in time in the past. Consider if we set a meeting for some time in the future at 2PM local time which is DST when we set the meeting, it gets stored as a specific UTC timestamp (say, 7PM UTC), and then *after that*, the local government cancels DST for that year. When you convert back from UTC, your lookup table will say "7PM UTC = 1PM", and now our local-time meeting has been moved. See [this post](https://coffeeonthekeyboard.com/storing-date-time-and-timezone-for-future-events-1339/) for more details.

Comment: @paul: The OP wants to display event dates in local time that have already occurred.

Comment: @martineau OP doesn't say whether they have occurred already or not. [This other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40061373/best-practice-for-storing-event-dates?noredirect=1&lq=1) from the same OP seems to indicate that these are conferences and other events that have yet to take place.