# Best Practice for Storing Event Dates

Tags: javascript, python, date, datetime

I am building an mobile app for event notifications. I scrape events from various websites. In my app I list events near a clients location and I allow them to search for events that could be located anywhere in the world. Since the event dates are fixed in some timezone they don't need to be converted into the app clients local time.

My question is how should I store these dates? I have so far tried to store them as UTC timestamps but my app users in other parts of the world are seeing their dates shifted by a day.

My python code is as follows. This generates the UTC timestamp that I then store in my database. The dateString is the date taken from the website.

```
return int(time.mktime(time.strptime(dateString, "%Y-%m-%d")))
```

In my app I convert the UTC timestamp to a human readable format:

```
/**
 * @summary Format date string
 *
 * @param date {Integer} Unix time stamp
 *
 * @return date {String}
 */
function formatDate( date ) {
    var m_names = new Array( "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec" ),
        d = new Date( date ),
        curr_date = d.getUTCDate(),
        curr_month = d.getUTCMonth(),
        curr_year = d.getUTCFullYear();

        return curr_date + "-" + m_names[ curr_month ] + "-" + curr_year;
}
```

I also am not concerned with the actual time that the conference starts/ends - just the date. In essence I need some guidance on how I can store/retrieve literal dates while allowing me some flexibility in the future to do things like query for all events that start in the next month.

I received some good advice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40033043/date-conversion-on-server-in-different-timezone) on how I can achieve this in my current app but I am in the process of re-engineering the platform now so I would like some advice on how I should proceed.

Comment: "Best" infers some criteria for comparison. If you get dates without a time zone, how do you know what time they represent? The most common method is to use ISO 8601 extended format date and time strings with a zero offset, then allow the host Date to convert them to "local" times. Note that `new Date('2016-10-10T00:00:00')` will be treated as local but `new Date('2016-10-10')` as UTC, which might explain the 1 day difference if those users are west of Greenwich. Also, it is not a good idea to ever parse strings with the Date constructor (or Date.parse).

Comment: Since these events take place in the future, you should not be storing them as UTC time stamps, you should be storing them as date + time + time zone (or, in this case just date + time zone). Sounds to me like your problem is you are storing a date as a datetime.